# Why OSX cp -avr get this error: the -R and -r options may not be specified together?

Tags: cp

I just want to copy a folder tree to another place like this:

```
cp -avr /blah/blah/htdocs ./
```

but I got error:

```
cp: the -R and -r options may not be specified together.
```

I followed this tutorial: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/copy-folder-linux-command-line/
It's about Linux, while I am using Mac. I found I can work around by using -avR instead. 
However, I am wondering why -avr could result in the odd error on Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OS X is not Linux, but closer to BSD. According to the [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cp.1.html), there's no `-r` switch on `cp` for OS X. There used to be one, yet:

> Historic versions of the cp utility had a -r option. This implementation supports that option; however, its use is strongly discouraged, as it does not correctly copy special files, symbolic links, or fifo's.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

`$ cp -iprv SOURCE NEWDIRECTORY`

Thanks to http://befused.com/freebsd/copy-directory

> -iprv are options for the cp command:
>
> - i - Interactive. Prompt you if overwriting any files
> - p - Preserve file attributes like date, time, etc
> - r - Recursive. Will copy subdirectories
> - v - Verbose. Show you each file as it is copied in the
>     command line console